# How to bind click event with amp-img

Tags: amp-html

I get the following error on validation when binding onclick event with amp-img.

> The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'amp-img'

Code works fine in browser but while validating amp pages it generates error. How to fix?

Comment: Please share the code

Answer (score 5):

`onclick` is a default html attribute to fire custom javascript, which is not allowed in amp.

You have to use the binding syntax of amp, which could look like this (last 4 lines):

```html
<amp-img
    src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/amp.jpg"
    width="1080"
    height="610"
    layout="responsive"
    alt="AMP"
    on="tap:AMP.setState({…})"
    tabindex="0"
    role="button">
</amp-img>
```

For `onclick="…"` it is `on="tap:…"` but there are also many other events you can use. Here is a [list](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/#element-specific-events).

Don't forget to set `tabindex` and `role` attributes when you use `tap` events on custom elements. Otherwise you get new validation errors.